# Design for an Android app (pharmacy duties)

Tags: design-patterns, android

I am creating an android app for pharmacy duties for different cities.

My approach:

I created an `Interface` with method `getDuties`, and for every cities I create a class named with name of the city
example:

```
public class AthensProvider extends CityProvider
```

Inside this class, I have the logic for parsing and returning duty objects.

Finally, in when the user changes city preference I have something like this:

```
CityProvider provider = ProviderHelper.getProvider(city);
provider.getDuties();
```

Is this approach correct?

Comment: What happens if you want to add a new city ? Do you need to recompile and redeploy your app ?

Comment: @X.L.Ant I am adding all available cities ( all cities in my country) in the first version of my app.

Comment: Seriously ? What's so special in each city provider that each needs a dedicated class for it ? Why not just a CityProvider property that would host the city name ?

Comment: I would have to agree. Are each city really unique in this matter, or could it be achieved by a simple CityProvider instance, with different data depending on which city? For me it seems like a massive redundancy and overhead to create a different class for each city.

Comment: @NiklasH The scraping for each city is entirely different. Each city has it's own site where they provide the duties, I parse and save them in a local db for each day.

Comment: If the scraping is unique for each city, I can see your point. If only the site is different, this should just be a data property instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Duties sounds like something that should be in a database or configuration file. Having custom code in your app for each city sound like a maintenance nightmare waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

If duties will not ever change over time or will change very rarely (e.g. once in a quarter), it may be a good idea to hardcode them in code rather than using a database.

In this case you could try an enum-based design:

```java
public enum Duties {
    ATHENS {
      public String[] getDuties() {
        return {"a", "b"};
      }
    },

    SPARTA {
      public String[] getDuties() {
        return {"c", "d"};
      }
    };

    abstract public String[] getDuties();
}
```

Then you will be able to get duties with following code:

```java
Duties.ATHENS.getDuties()
```

In case of hardcoding anything it's always a good idea to rationalize it a comment.

If duties will change often you may want to consider storing duties for each city in a data base and synchronizing them with information stored on the server during application's start-up.

Comment: Why could it ever be a good idea to hardcode duties?

Comment: Less files in the project, less platform components used, less IO, less dependencies, less maintainance work.